# Image SizeChanged Event is fires only one in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am having image control. I am setting image from gallery and camera, then setting image width and height based on captured images. For that I use size changed event, it working for the first time. then i removed that image and set the image again that time the size changed event is not triggering. how can i trigger image Size Changed method for every time  setting the image

Comment: I guess that you could use [PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.propertychanged?view=xamarin-forms) event and check if the property that changed was the Source, and the trigger whatever you like from there

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove that image" ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like the size didn't change - the second time used the same size image, right? Therefore there was no reason for SizeChanged event to fire. Try setting image source to `null`, then setting it to the new image. That might convince Xamarin there is a change.